# Creating and changing into directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

So maybe Python works differently than I am imagining it in my head. What I want to do is create a directory, "cd" into it, create another directory and then "cd" into that one. Every time I print out what directory I am in, i keep getting the one my current .py is in. Am I missing something?

```py
#variables
current_dir = os.getcwd()
build_dir = "./../Documents/Releases/"
prod_folder = "./Products"
prod_dir = "./Products/Project"

# Path to directory
print("Current Directory: %s" % current_dir)
os.chdir(build_dir)
build_no = input("Enter the build branch/build number: ")

#created new directory
print("Current Directory: %s" % current_dir)
if not os.path.exists(build_no):
    os.mkdir(build_no)
    print("Directory ", build_no, " created.")
else:
    print("Directory ", build_no, "already exists.")

# This works fine up to here. I "cd" into where I need to and the new
# folder/directory is created, after here is where I am having issues.

#cd into Products/Project
print("Current Directory: %s" % current_dir)
if not os.path.exists(prod_folder):
    os.mkdir(prod_folder)
os.chdir(prod_dir)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should call `print("Current Directory: %s" % os.getcwd())`. By using `print("Current Directory: %s" % current_dir)`, you're printing the same variable over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to @Alassane comment for the fixing the issue. As for why it is happening, all you are doing is calling the `current_dir` variable that has been set the when the `os.getcwd()` **function call happened in the first line**. So when ever you are referring to the variable `current_dir` it is just printing the same value over and over again.

Comment: Yeah, I am going to no print out every time I change directories. I was able to fix this issue by just setting each folder/directory as it's own variable and just using `os.chdir()` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

So this issue has been resolved but I have a follow up task I want to do. One of my goals with this code is to automate a process. Part of that process is wanted to open xcode and then archive the .xcworkspace I open. One of my co-workers told me that was possible. I am still learning Python, but I am not sure how I would automate mouse clicks or commands on another program. Any tips?